# Copy complete row from one sheet into another using total rows from first sheet as variable

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy rows from one sheet, then inside that logical loop, copy rows from another sheet that match values from the row copied from sheet 1. Then repeat this process for every line of the first sheet, using a boolean value to record whether any rows were not matched and copy those rows to a fourth sheet.

However that is some way off.

Initially I want to copy each row from one sheet into a second sheet. This is my code but it only copies the first row of the information and if the first row is empty it stops.

This will definitely be something simple but I do not see it.

```
Sub test()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim k As Long

    k = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    If k = 1048576 Then
        k = 1
    End If
    For i = 1 To sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy Destination:= Sheets("Sheet3").Rows(i)
    Exit For
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have some empty rows that trip you up since .End(xlDown) will stop at the first empty row. It also sounds like you want to iterate until the last available record. In which case, change how you determine the last row by counting from the bottom

sh.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Rows.Count

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `Exit For` and it should work.

```
Sub test()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim k As Long

k = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
If k = 1048576 Then
    k = 1
End If
For i = 1 To sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Rows(i)
Next i
End Sub
```